# Cannot display Plotly chart with Panel DateRangeSlider widget

Tags: python, plotly, panel

I am currently struggling with a chart where I am using a DateRangeSlider to update my chart based on the date interval.

The dataframe is similar to the attached table ['new_item'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJSei.png) where the y axis is the count, the x axis is the equipment and the color coding corresponds to the payment method. I have converted the date with datetime.strptime() to get a '%Y-%m-%d' format, enabling to combine rows with the same attributes (equipment and payment method) and sum up on the Count column.
The date slider has datetime format and the Purchase_Date column is of the type object.

I am using Plotly as I would like to get an interactive bar chart when hovering over the bars. The chart should be of this kind [Bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qEik.png). I used the code below which didn't produce any output or error message.

Any idea why the figure isn't returned? Is it an issue with the date format?

```
date = pn.widgets.DateRangeSlider(name="Date Range",
    start=new_item.PURCHASE_DATE.min(), end=dt.date.today(),
    value=(new_item.PURCHASE_DATE.min(), dt.date.today())
)


import panel as pn
pn.extension("plotly")

@pn.depends(date)
def new_item_purchased(date):
    item_date= new_item[new_item.PURCHASE_DATE == date]
    fig = px.bar(item_date, x = 'Equipment', y = 'Count', color= 'Payment_method', log_y=True, 
                 color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Dark24)
    
    plt.close(fig)
    return fig

pn.Column(pn.Column(date),new_item_purchased)
```

Comment: Please, share the exact code you used. Also, share the dataframe in a string format (`new_item.to_string()`) so that we can easily copy it :)

Comment: Here is the df in a string format:
'      Equipment Payment method Purchase Date  Count\n0         Mower           Cash    2022-03-12      8\n1          Rake         Checks    2022-01-23     12\n2         Mower    Credit Card    2022-04-05      1\n3  Flower seeds           Cash    2022-02-02      3'

Comment: For the code, I initially query a company's DB to extract the data. My initial dataframe is called 'result' and after some data manipulation, I ended-up with the new_item dataframe. 
On the "result" dataframe, I aplied the following code to convert the date initially in the format 2022-01-03 15:04:56.
```result['PURCHASE DATE'] = result.PURCHASE DATE.apply(lambda x:x.date())```.

Comment: Then, as I removed the time, I got some duplicate data on the same date so I used
```new_item = result[['Equipment', 'Payment method', 'Purchase date', 'Count']].groupby(['Equipment', 'Payment method', 'Purchase date']).sum().reset_index()```

Comment: the first part of the code works, I am getting the widget but can't get the chart + the widget to get displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are only interested in dates, and not times, I would convert `"Purchase_Date"` to `dt.date`.

If you use a `pn.widgets.DateRangeSlider`, then `date` is a list of two dates! In the following I'm going to switch to a `pn.widgets.DateSlider`, with which `date` is a `date` object.

You also used `plt.close(fig)`. Please don't mix matplolib (`plt.close`) with Plotly. They are two very different libraries: they are not designed to work together.

Note that with `pn.config.throttled = True` I'm activating the throttling: the function will be executed only on mouse-up event on the slider! This makes it easy to work with bigger dataframes.

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import plotly.express as px
import panel as pn
pn.extension("plotly")
pn.config.throttled = True

new_item = pd.read_csv(StringIO(" Equipment Payment_method Purchase_Date Count\n0 Mower Cash 2022-03-12 8\n1 Rake Checks 2022-01-23 12\n2 Mower Credit_Card 2022-04-05 1\n3 Flower_seeds Cash 2022-02-02 3"), sep=" ", index_col=0)

new_item["Purchase_Date"] = new_item["Purchase_Date"].apply(lambda t: dt.date.fromisoformat(t))

date_slider = pn.widgets.DateSlider(
    name='Date Slider',
    start=new_item.Purchase_Date.min(), end=new_item.Purchase_Date.max(),
    value=new_item.Purchase_Date.max()
)

@pn.depends(date_slider)
def new_item_purchased(date):
    results = new_item[new_item["Purchase_Date"] == date]
    return px.bar(results, x = 'Equipment', y = 'Count', color= 'Payment_method', log_y=True, 
                 color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Dark24)

pn.Column(pn.Column(date_slider), new_item_purchased)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works when the dataframe is in a string format. What can I use instead of fromisoformat if I am running the code on a dataframe where the purchase_date is in datetime64[ns] type?

Comment: `new_item["Purchase_Date"] = new_item['Purchase_Date'].dt.date` should do the trick. Please mark this answer as the solution to your question :)